# Do electronics companies publish the diagram of their electric boards

Tags: schematics, datasheet, diagram

**I'm new to the electronics world**, and I came to know that electronics companies (As Fairchild) provide datasheet for the components they produce (As IGBT, Triac, etc.).

**Do electronics companies (As Samsung, LG, Sony, etc.) provide a datasheets & a diagrams for the electric boards in their devices?**

**If the answer is NO!** Then how can you tell what component is connected to other components in an electric board that you are fixing for a better diagnosis of the problem, especially with the existence of the "Surface" components as (Capacitors, Resistance, Optocoupler, etc.)?

**If the answer is YES!** Where can I find these diagrams?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Often the answer is yes. But not always.

Comment: If you're a repair tech you can get (probably buy) very detailed schematics from Apple.

Comment: @DKNguyen Does Apple offer the diagram of the electric boards from other companies?

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy I doubt it. Not sure if this question is sarcastic or not.

Comment: @DKNguyen There's no space for sarcasm in an educational place.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy, hmmmm, also sarcasm? ... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the manufacturer provides a **service manual**, it would be there. In the very old days it was common to have the schematics inside the manual or sometimes even glued to the inside of the case on old television sets, but those days are long gone. For test and lab equipment sometimes the schematics are provided with the detailed user manual.

Most consumer products are very reliable and not easy to fix so it makes little sense to make schematics available to to the public.

Sometimes 3rd parties like Sam's will provide service manuals.

Even without service manuals, looking for power supply problems and obvious connections between subsystems, backlight inverters and so on can allow a substantial subset of common issues to be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe all circuits are public. Maybe here and there you can find some. They used to be maybe 40 years ago, I saw once schemes of tv sets- for technicians who were able to fix them, which is a sort of a lost skill.

But the question is, why would you need it. Obviously not to fix. If you need a reference design, there is plenty of material available, for more or less anything.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, really appreciated. How can I search (Google) for the diagram of a circuit that I'm diagnosis, assuming it's out there? As for your question, I need to see the connection between the board elements so I can hunt down the malfunction component(s) that's causing the problem, and for that I need to have the diagram of the circuit.

Comment: What are you trying to repair?

Comment: I'm trying to repair my Samsung Topload washing machine. Its "Start" function isn't working just like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52NltT5C8Es But in his case the power & logic circuits in one board, while mine they're separated (DC9201450A) https://www.google.com/search?q=dc9201450a&sxsrf=ALeKk03UrGy7ey56LQDNk3_YRULuknFf4w:1588150012923&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj85Prqn43pAhX0BWMBHdYmB5MQ_AUoAXoECAMQAw&biw=1366&bih=633#imgrc=sksuZ2sg0YonhM

Comment: He solved the problem by removing an SMD Capacitor number (c160). This capacitor in my electric board is connected to the Anod & Cathode of an Optocoupler. I checked the resistance of c160 & it moved upward to infinity (I think it's OK). I checked the Triacs using a breadboard & a motor & I think they're OK. I ran out of ideas of the source of the problem.

Comment: Look, economically you should betting find a replacement, maybe buy it. Otherwise you need some measurement tools and a ton of experience to fix it.

Comment: What measurement tools (Just mention the names and I'll Google them)? I'm passionate about learning electronics and this's a good study case that helped me to learn a lot and I know that I still have a long way ahead of me, but you have to start somewhere, right.

Comment: Tools are DVM and oscilloscope. But trust me, this is not the way to learn electronics. You have to start from text books, there is plenty of material available from any university.